# Print results at conclusion of bash 'for loop'

Tags: bash, unix, for-loop, ffmpeg

I'm a beginner.
I have a Bash script that embeds subtitles into mkv files if they exist in a directory.

```
for i in *.mkv; do
    if [ -f "${i%mkv}"*"srt" ]; then
        ffmpeg -i "$i" -f srt -i "${i%mkv}"*"srt" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s srt $i.output.mkv
        mv "${i%mkv}"*"srt" "${i%mkv}srt".old
        mv $i $i.old
        mv $i.output.mkv $i
    else
        echo $i "does not have srt file"
    fi
done
```

It looks for all .mkv files that have an associated .srt file and does some ffmpeg magic to it. If it does not find an associated .srt file it says that the .mkv file "does not have srt file."

How can I make it so that at the conclusion of the for loop I get a print out of all the .mkv files that did have an .srt file and did successfully do all the other actions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a [Bash array](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html) to store completed or skipped MKVs:

```
SUCCESSMKVS=()
SKIPMKVS=()

for i in *.mkv; do
    if [ -f "${i%mkv}"*"srt" ]; then
        ffmpeg -i "$i" -f srt -i "${i%mkv}"*"srt" -map 0:0 -map 0:1 \
            -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s srt "${i}.output.mkv"
        mv "${i%mkv}"*"srt" "${i%mkv}srt".old
        mv "$i" "${i}.old"
        mv "${i}.output.mkv" "$i"
        SUCCESSMKVS+=("$i")
    else
        echo $i "does not have srt file"
        SKIPMKVS+=("$i")
    fi
done

echo "The following MKVs succeeded:"
for mkv in "${SUCCESSMKVS[@]}"; do
    echo -e "\t${mkv}"
done
echo

echo "The following MKVs were skipped:"
for mkv in "${SKIPMKVS[@]}"; do
    echo -e "\t${mkv}"
done
echo
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the very fast help. I'll work on trying it in a second. I'm also trying to incorporate .mkv OR .mp4 and so far I've gotten to 'for i in *.{mkv,mp4}; do'. Any quick thoughts on how to incorporate the mp4 part in all the other pattern matching parts? (like ${i%mkv}")

Comment: Use `"$(basename "$i")"` instead of `"${i%mkv}"`. Note that this will remove the `.` too. No problem, glad to help!